# Changing message for timeout using Jasmine done

Tags: jasmine

For now I have the following code...

```
it("takes a long time", function(done) {});
```

Problem is when it times out I get the following message...

> Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout
>   specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Can I change this message to something more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an error regarding your test, not an error of the code you're testing. If your test is properly written, you shouldn't encounter that error. The test itself is timing out. If you're writing a test to see how/whether some code times out, you would write the test to handle that, rather than the test just throwing an error because you didn't call `done()` in time.

```
// this function times out if passed "true" as second argument
function testThis(done, shouldTimeout) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    shouldTimeout || done();
  }, 500);
}

it("timed out", function(done) {
  var timedOut = false;
  setTimeout(function() {
    testThis(function() {
      // this shouldn't be called because we're telling `testThis` to timeout
      timedOut = true;
    }. true);
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    expect(timedOut).toBeFalsy();
    done();
  }, 505);
});
```

If you needed to wait a long time to see if something times out, you can change how long Jasmine will wait before a test throws a timeout error by changing `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;`

Jasmine does have [**a mock**](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_JavaScript_Timeout_Functions) for `setInterval` and `setTimeout` that let you run that code synchronously, and saves all that wasted time waiting.